# Integrated Security SSPI meaning

Tags: sql-server, authentication, iis

I have a question about the meaning of "Integrated Security=SSPI" in the web.config file of a web application. I have a web application running in IIS which is accessing a SQL Server Express database installed in Windows authentication mode. The web application is accessed by typing in a domain address (http://servername:portnumber/Default.aspx) on the network. 
Only domain users can access this url.
As I understand it, the meaning of "Integrated Security=SSPI" is "The current Windows account credentials are used for authentication".
This cannot be the credentials of the user who is viewing the url because I have not given the user rights on that database in SQL server. Is it the AppPool of the site in IIS?
Thank you for any replies.

Comment: You can see under what account you are logged in using sys.dm_exec_sessions (login_name field)